# Loading another webpage into a div on current page

Tags: javascript, html, cors

I've read a lot on CORS, tried a variety of methods, but nothing so far has allowed me to accomplish what I am seeking to do.

I am working with two subdomains that are on the same ultimate domain:

```
a.test.com
b.test.com
```

The user is currently on a.test.com, and while I can create a hyperlink that will send them off to a page on b.test.com, the customer has asked whether or not I can take the particular functions that the user would accomplish on b.test.com and load them within the user's same initial page on a.test.com so they can do everything they need to do from one tab instead of two separate tabs.

I have access to edit anything on a.test.com, but I am unable to set any headers or change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on b.test.com, so I keep getting hit with CORS errors.

I have tried:

- setting `document.domain` = 'test.com' on a.test.com
- setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on a.test.com
- read over the use of CORS proxies, but have not tried using one
- read over jsonP and loading the page contents with PHP, but neither of these work as I need *interactivity* with the actual webpage, not just data
- using iframes

I've googled and searched SO but it seems like what I am trying to do is not possible without being able to change things on b.test.com as well.  Am I spinning my wheels on something impossible here?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: apache xampp for a.test.com - not sure about b.test.com

Comment: Use iFrame mate.

Comment: I see. Only familiar with enabling CORS on IIS. However, I ran into the same issue and what I did was I went into the web.config file (config file for IIS) and wrote access control allow origin on IIS. However, for apache you probably already set that rule for the .htaccess file. If that doesn't work possibly look into trying an Iframe?

Comment: Even using an iframe I get the exact same error: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin....from accessing a cross-origin frame.`  My understanding is that what is blocking me is a setting on `b.test.com`, not anything with apache on `a.test.com`.  Am I incorrect on that?

Comment: You need to set the `document.domain = 'test.com'` on both

Comment: I don't have access to make changes to `b.test.com`.